# Kernel 6.6+ update -> No sound from speakers on Lenovo Legion 7 16ACHg6

Tags: fedora, kernel, audio

Good day.

I've installed Fedora 39 (Gnome) recently and at first everything was working fine. However, after updating my system (specifically kernel) I noticed that my laptop's speakers stopped working.

Kernel 6.5 - > speakers work fine
Kernel 6.6+ -> speakers don't work

[alsa-info.sh](https://alsa-project.org/db/?f=098bcb5cc0c7b2403be7516fd8da7cc1305830d3)

inxi -aA
https://pastebin.com/efdBP0bf

systemctl –user status pipewire
https://pastebin.com/f2k01UUP

systemctl –user status pipewire-pulse
https://pastebin.com/Vq1cZ6h8

pw-dump 0
https://pastebin.com/R8yMynfe

systemctl –user status wireplumber
https://pastebin.com/LuGdn97A

wpctl status
https://pastebin.com/YxXg6Tq2

System Info
https://pastebin.com/EJZ0m37b

Is there anything I can do to make it work with the current kernel?

The only other alternative I see is to use the previous one.

Regards.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I can confirm this reproduces on NixOS unstable on the exact same hardware and kernel, and reverting to LTS fixes it. So it's probably an actual kernel bug and not a Fedora bug.